# attrTween function not being called

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on creating "bands" via an d3.svg.arc function. I am aware that `.transition()` does not have a great default interpolator for arcs, so I defined my own using `attrTween`. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
var bandArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius)
  .outerRadius(radius + 20)
  .padAngle(0.03)
  .cornerRadius(2)
  .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.PI - d.radians[0]; })
  .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.PI - d.radians[1]; });

var bands = nodeGroup.selectAll('path.band')
  .data(bands, getBandKey);

// Old bands
bands.exit().call(fadeOut);

// Current bands
bands
  .transition()
  .attrTween('d', function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function(t) {
      console.log('BLAH');
      return bandArc(i(t));
    };
  })
  .attr('d', bandArc);

// New bands
bands.enter()
  .append('path')
  .classed('band', true)
  .attr('d', bandArc)
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
    return d.color;
  });
```

Problem 1 is that I NEVER see the log statement (`console.log('BLAH');`).

Problem 2 is that when there are new bands, I get an `Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d` error for ever new band coming in.

It actually does a decent job minus the errors and the lack of logging, but I'd rather not have the errors piling up in the browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're calling both `.attrTween()` and `.attr()` on the same attribute. You don't need the `.attr()`, which I think is cancelling the transition in this case.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff! Make it an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're overriding the transition immediately after initialising it:

```
.transition()
.attrTween('d', function(d) { ... })
.attr('d', ...)
```

By setting the value of `d` directly, you're disabling the transition on the same attribute. To fix, simply remove the call to `.attr("d", ...)`.